# How to cover {get;set;} in Test Class code coverage?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Below class DTO used in another class MyController. The issue is DTO class get 100% code coverage but I am not able to code coverage more than 50% for MyController class. Need help in TestMyController test class.

**Class : DTO**

```
 public class DTO{

    public String categoryCode {get;set;}
    public Date dueDate {get;set;}
    public Id account {get;set;}
    public Decimal amount {get;set;}

    }
```

**Class : MyController**

```
public with sharing class  MyController{

    public Trans__c invoice {get;set;}
    public Trans__c inputObject{get;set;}

    public List<DTO> d {get {
        if(d == null){
            d = new List<DTO>();
        }
        return d;
    }set;}

    //createDT() method call on Button click from VF Page
    public PageReference createDT(){

    Id invoiceId = (Id)ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 

    invoice  = [Select Id,Name,Account__c,Due_Date__c,CategoryCode__c,Amount__c from 
                Trans__c where Id=:invoiceId];

    inputObject = new Trans__c();
    inputObject.Id = invoice.Id;

    DTO dto = new DTO();
    dto.categoryCode= inputObject.CategoryCode__c;
    dto.dueDate =inputObject.Due_date__c;  
    dto.account =invoice.Account__c ; 
    dto.amount =inputObject.Amount__c; 

    return null;
    }
}
```

**Test Class : TestMyController**

```
@isTest
    private class TestMyController{
        static testmethod void testCase(){   
            Account__c acc = new Account__c();
            acc.Name = 'Test';
            insert acc;

            Trans__c t = new Trans__c();
            t.CategoryCode__c = 'Test';
            t.Account__c = acc.Id;
            t.Due_Date__c = System.today();
            t.Amount__c = 1000.5;
            insert t;

            DTO dto = new DTO();
            dto.categoryCode= t.CategoryCode__c;
            dto.dueDate =t.Due_date__c;  
            dto.account =t.Account__c ; 
            dto.amount =t.Amount__c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should try covering MyController class instead of DTO.

Comment: Got 100% code coverage in TestDTO test class. Issue in TestMyContoller test class.

Comment: Wrapper/inner class should not be tested, you always test the main class which internally calls inner class.

Comment: Yh, you are right but can you help me to solve this issue. How do i cover the DTO class object assignment in MyController class.

Comment: It would be good exercise for you, let us know if you are stuck in a specific issue.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want 100% code coverage? What you want is to cover the business requirements. By focusing on covering the different business cases, you will find that coverage goes up automatically. I find that 80-90% is often enough to cover all business cases. Many other lines (exception handling, etc), don't necessarily need to be covered and are implementation-specific. If you cover 100% of the code, you will not be able to change your implementation (ie: refactor) without changing the tests. If you cover business cases, you can refactor at will.

Comment: @mkorman But at least, I need minimum 75% code coverage for the deployment. And till now I am getting only 56%. If you could, help me with this.

Comment: @TejasKadia I don't want to sound harsh, but you're missing the basics here. Your test method (s) (you'll likely need more than one) need to *instantiate* an instance of `MyController` and call its public methods. I suggest you do some reading on unit testing in general, and then on Apex unit testing, to understand the basics. Without a grasp of the basics you will only do "monkey see, monkey do" copy and paste code. There are plenty of free resources on unit testing and TDD. Once you know those, porting those concepts to Apex is trivial.

Comment: @mkorman I tried same as you described. But still not cover the portion after 'DTO dto = new DTO();' If you have an idea, Here you can comment few syntax related to it.